# Nuka-carousel custom arrow button

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to nuka-carousel react.I'm trying to add prev-next arrow button instead of just 'prev' and 'next' written button. I've found various solutions where a decorator function is written.I have tried it but havn't found my desired output.
Here is my code:

```
import Carousel from 'nuka-carousel';
import createReactClass from 'create-react-class';
var Decorators = [
    {
        component: createReactClass({
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <i className="fa fa-arrow-left" onClick={this.props.previousSlide} aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }),
        position: 'CenterLeft',
        style: {
            padding: 20
        }
    },
    {
        component: createReactClass({
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <i className="fa fa-arrow-right" onClick={this.props.nextSlide} aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }),
        position: 'CenterRight',
        style: {
            padding: 20
        }
    }
];

return(
    <Carousel decortators={Decorators} slidesToShow={3} cellSpacing={50} >
        {cards}
    </Carousel>

);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you need to set [`render*Controls`](https://formidable.com/open-source/nuka-carousel/api#rendertopleftcontrols) prop of your `Carousel` component (where * is specific place of control, such as `CenterLeft` or `CenterRight`):

```
<Carousel
  renderCenterLeftControls={({ previousSlide }) => (
    <button onClick={previousSlide}>
      <i className="fa fa-arrow-left" />
    </button>
  )}
  renderCenterRightControls={({ nextSlide }) => (
    <button onClick={nextSlide}>
      <i className="fa fa-arrow-right"/>
    </button>
  )}
>
  {cards}
</Carousel>
```

UPD: the link to docs was updated

Comment: My guy! Thank you